# How do I make a SQL table from the result of another select?

Tags: sql, mysql

I'm asking for MySQL specifically, but the answer might work for a lot of SQL databases.

If I have a select statement like this:

```
select * from users where age > 5;
```

How do I assign that to a new table?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
insert into old_farts
select * from users where age > 5;
```

[Here's](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/insert-select.html) the reference page.

Comment: It's worth noting that you have to create the destination table first.

Comment: `CREATE TABLE AS ... SELECT` is the right answer, as mentioned by Bob.

Answer (score 5):

At least in Oracle you can do something like

```
CREATE TABLE SOME_KIDS AS
  SELECT * FROM USERS WHERE AGE > 5;
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to use the `INSERT...SELECT` syntax -

`INSERT INTO NewTable SELECT * FROM Users WHERE AGE > 5`

(Edited to add: In SQL that would be `SELECT * INTO NewTable FROM Users WHERE AGE > 5`)

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like what you actually want is a [view](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-view.html).

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW users_over_five AS (SELECT * FROM users WHERE age > 5);
```

Unless you want a [non-normalized database](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization), or are just moving data around for maintenance, a view is the way to go.